# Combining mutate and text search in R

Tags: r, search

I'm trying to make new columns that indicates if a given word is within a larger sentence, such that I could filter all participants who used the word "slow" or "happy" in a comment section.

As a simple example...

```
fruit_list = data.frame(c("apple", "bannana", "cherries"))

person <- seq(1:3)
comment <- c("I like apple pie", "The worst flavor is bannana", "Those cherries are cheap")
df <- data.frame(person,comment)

for (i in 1:nrow(fruit_list)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(df)){
    df[i,j+2] <- (as.integer(grepl(fruit_list[i,], df[j,2], fixed=TRUE)))
  }
}
```

The above code works in that it correctly places a 0 or 1, but as I scaled it up to larger lists of words to search for (i.e. fruits) and more sentences (i.e. comments), it (not surprisingly) gets very slow.

I was wondering if using a mutate approach would be more efficient, doing something like this

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
  apple = as.integer(grepl(fruit_list[1,], comment, fixed =TRUE))
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
  bannana = as.integer(grepl(fruit_list[2,], comment, fixed =TRUE))
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
  cherries = as.integer(grepl(fruit_list[3,], comment, fixed =TRUE))
  )
```

The only problem here is I can't figure out how to cycle through the items in the list of fruit so I had to directly code the names.  For three items that is manageable, but I want this to scale up to dozens of search terms.  I've used simple sapply and lapply before, but I'm not sure how to use them in this more complicated scenario.

I'm betting there is some way to pull the name of the mutated column from the list and use that same value as the search term for the grepl, but I just can't piece it together.

Any suggestions would be appreciated- even ones that go in entirely different directions from what I've tried.

Comment: why are you looping over each row? you only need one loop `df[, fruit_list[, 1]] <- lapply(fruit_list[, 1], function(x) +(grepl(x, df$comment)))`

Comment: That looks like what I thought the answer might be, but when I run the code it errors out with "Error in fruit_list[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` and `purrr::map_dfc`. It is easier to use a vector of fruits, instead of a data.frame:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

fruits<-c("apple", "bannana", "cherries")

map_dfc(fruits, ~+grepl(.x, comment)) %>%
    set_names(fruits) %>%
    bind_cols(df, .)
```

Or just with:

```
df %>% mutate(set_names(map_dfc(fruits, ~ +grepl(.x, comment)), fruits))
```

output

```
  person                     comment apple bannana cherries
1      1            I like apple pie     1       0        0
2      2 The worst flavor is bannana     0       1        0
3      3    Those cherries are cheap     0       0        1
```

Comment: df %>% mutate(set_names(map_dfc(fruits, ~ +grepl(.x, comment)), fruits))  worked well when I used it on a subset of my real data.  However, when I ran in on a larger portion of my dataset then I got the error. Error in rm(list = names_bindings, envir = bindings) : 
  variable names are limited to 10000 bytes".  I guess I need to do some data cleanup outside of R.  Thanks for the suggestions anyway.

Comment: I am glad I could help. You most likely need to do some data wrangling to handle this inconsistent naming issue, and then you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(names = str_extract(comment, fruit_list),
         values = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = names,
              values_from = values,
              values_fill = 0)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  person comment                     apple bannana cherries
   <int> <chr>                       <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1      1 I like apple pie                1       0        0
2      2 The worst flavor is bannana     0       1        0
3      3 Those cherries are cheap        0       0        1
```

**Note:** I changed your `fruit_list` from data.frame into a vector (for simplification). In your example, you could use `fruit_list[,1]` instead of vector `fruit_list`.

Comment: This solution works with the predefined list of fruits, but if I change the input to c("apple", "bannana", "grapes") then it fails to find a column name for third one, but still assigns a value of '1' in the third row of that column.

Comment: @user17591274 The third column is named `NA` in this case. Do you want to have three columns and the third one filled with `0`? Perhaps [rawr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70230707/combining-mutate-and-text-search-in-r/70230803?noredirect=1#comment124148912_70230707)'s proposed solution is a better option for you?